# How to create custom reminders in lighning with javascript?

Tags: javascript, thunderbird, lightning

I am creating an extension to import todos from a CRM to thunderbird/lightning. I use the calITodo interface to create my todos :

```
var todo = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/calendar/todo;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.calITodo);
```

But I can't find how to set reminders, or create a custom one for my todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer this question a bit wider to show you the alternatives, you may already be doing this.

If you would like to use the CRM as a backend for a calendar, you may want to write a "Provider" type extension, similar to the Provider for Google Calendar. You just need to implement a few methods for the usual operations (get/add/modify/delete) to get started. See the [source code for the Provider for Google Calendar](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/calendar/providers/gdata/) as a starting point.

If you would just like to do a one time import, then you are probably going in the right direction. Just use the addItem/adoptIte method on the calendar in question. If you need a dialog to select calendars, you can [reuse this one](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/calendar/base/content/dialogs/chooseCalendarDialog.xul), it is available via the uri chrome://calendar/content/chooseCalendarDialog.xul.

Now to get to your real question. To add a reminder to an event or todo the following code helps. Of course you can choose a different alarm relation.

```
Components.utils.import("resource://calendar/modules/calUtils.jsm");

let todo = cal.createToDo();
let alarm = cal.createAlarm();
let alarmDate = cal.createDateTime();

alarm.related = Components.interfaces.calIAlarm.ALARM_RELATED_ABSOLUTE;
alarm.alarmDate = alarmDate;

todo.addAlarm(alarm);
// ...
```

The alarm implements calIAlarm, you can find the [interface description here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/calendar/base/public/calIAlarm.idl). It is then added to the todo, which implements calITodo and also calIItemBase. For an overview of the alarm methods on an item, [see here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/calendar/base/public/calIItemBase.idl#154).

If you are interested what other utility functions are available, [see here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/find?string=calUtils.js&tree=comm-central). You can use functions from both files by merely importing calUtils.**jsm**. Just prefix each function with "cal.".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, really complete and useful. I still have a little issue that you could maybe solve. I can't find how to get all the todos of a calendar. I thought the functions getItem() and getItems() from the calICalendar Interface ([here](http://doxygen.db48x.net/mozilla-full/html/d7/dc7/interfacecalICalendar.html)) were the solution but I could not make it works properly.

Comment: I've already elaborated more on that question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645196/how-to-get-todos-from-thunderbird-lightning-calendars), please check my original answer.