# How to get todos from Thunderbird/Lightning calendars?

Tags: thunderbird, lightning

I can't find how to get all the todos of a calendar in Lightning. I thought the functions `getItem()` and `getItems()` from the `calICalendar` Interface ([here](http://doxygen.db48x.net/mozilla-full/html/d7/dc7/interfacecalICalendar.html)) were the solution but I could not make it work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going in the right direction. You just need to pass the flag that you want todos only. An example can be found [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/calendar/base/content/calendar-task-tree.xml?mark=992-1005#998).

To elaborate more on your example below, there are a few syntax errors and you might need different flags. I'm not sure why the alert is needed, that sounds to me like the event loop is not being spun. In what context are you calling these bits?

Try this:

```
var arrayItems = new Array();

var todoListener = {
    onOperationComplete: function(aCalendar, aStatus, aOperationType, aId, aDetail) {},
    onGetResult: function(aCalendar, aStatus, aItemType, aDetail, aCount, aItems) {  
        arrayItems = arrayItems.concat(aItems);
    }
};

var filter = aCalendar.ITEM_FILTER_TYPE_TODO | aCalendar.ITEM_FILTER_COMPLETED_ALL;
aCalendar.getItems(filter, 0, null, null, todoListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your example, I understood how to implement the listener which was my main problem.

So here what I code :

```
var arrayItem = new Array; ;

    var todoListener = 
    {
        onOperationComplete: function(aCalendar, aStatus, aOperationType, aId, aDetail) {},
        onGetResult: function(aCalendar, aStatus, aItemType, aDetail, aCount, aItems) 
        {    
            for (let i=0; i < aCount; i++) 
            {
                arrayItem.push(aItems[i]);
            }           
        }
    };

    var filter = aCalendar.ITEM_FILTER_ALL_ITEMS;
    filter |= aCalendar.ITEM_FILTER_TYPE_TODO;
    aCalendar.getItems(filter, 0, null, null, todoListener);
```

However, I have a really weird issue here. Actually, I do not get the todos with this code. I have to add an `alert("something");` after the getItems() method to get my arrayItem filled up. Else, it is empty.

Comment: The listener is asynchronous, you need to spin the event loop after your getItems call, or better yet change your pattern to continue processing in the listener or a nested function.